# processing values when user click submit

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a question regarding passing values inside the page to process it to the db. So i have this code, that when user press show a table is showed that is pulled from the DB and user shall press ok or reject to update the DB. My problem is when i press OK, an error is showing,

Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_approval\show_requested_component.php on line 43

I dont know where the error is, So any help would be greatly appreciated

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'show'){

  $requestCompParse = oci_parse($conn, $requestCompSql);
  oci_execute($requestCompParse);

  while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($requestCompParse)){

    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='post'>";
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>
      <th>PROJECT</th>
      <th>BASEPLATE</th>
      <th>THICKNESS</th>
      <th>QTY REQUESTED</th>
      <th>QTY REQUIRED</th>
      <th>QTY CNCED</th>
      <th>REQUESTER</th>   
      <th>REQ. DATE</th>
      <th align="center">ACTION</th>  
      </tr>
      </thead>';

    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr class='warning'><td>$row[PROJECT_NAME]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[BASE_PLATE]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[THICKNESS]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUESTED]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUIRED]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_CNCED]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[REQUESTER]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[REQUEST_DATE]</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
    <input type='button' value='REJECT' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "<table cellspacing = '0'";
    echo "</form>";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

      $qtyToBeInserted = ($row[QTY_REQUESTED] + $row[QTY_CNCED]);

      $approvedSql = "UPDATE COMPONENT_CUTTING SET QTY_CNCED = :qtyToBeInserted WHERE BASE_PLATE = :basePlate 
                      AND THICKNESS = :thick AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName";

      $approvedSqlParse = oci_parse($conn, $approvedSql);

      oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "qtyToBeInserted", $qtyToBeInserted);
      oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "basePlate", $row[BASE_PLATE]);
      oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "thick", $row[THICKNESS]);
      oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "projName", $row[PROJECT_NAME]);

      $approvedSqlRes = oci_execute($approvedSqlParse);

        if ($approvedSqlRes){
          oci_commit($conn);
        } else {
          oci_rollback($conn);
        }
      }  

    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: @cmorrissey line 43 is, if ($_POST['action'] == 'show'){

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring because your generated form does not have an element named `action`.  When you go to check the value of an array element, if that element does not exist in the array, instead of PHP saying to itself "Well, it's not here, so I'll call it FALSE" (or something along those lines), it says "Bah! It's not here! WTF do I do?!?!"  :)  So you have to hold PHP's hand a bit and check for the existence of the element first, and then, if it's there, check the value.

You should change your `if` statement to this.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'show'){
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I'd modify your code flow a bit and do something like this…

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'show'){

  $requestCompParse = oci_parse($conn, $requestCompSql);
  oci_execute($requestCompParse);

  while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($requestCompParse)){

    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='post'>";
    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>
      <th>PROJECT</th>
      <th>BASEPLATE</th>
      <th>THICKNESS</th>
      <th>QTY REQUESTED</th>
      <th>QTY REQUIRED</th>
      <th>QTY CNCED</th>
      <th>REQUESTER</th>   
      <th>REQ. DATE</th>
      <th align="center">ACTION</th>  
      </tr>
      </thead>';

    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr class='warning'><td>$row[PROJECT_NAME]<input type='hidden' name='PROJECT_NAME' value='$row[PROJECT_NAME]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[BASE_PLATE]<input type='hidden' name='BASE_PLATE' value='$row[BASE_PLATE]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[THICKNESS]<input type='hidden' name='THICKNESS' value='$row[THICKNESS]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUESTED]<input type='hidden' name='QTY_REQUESTED' value='$row[QTY_REQUESTED]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUIRED]<input type='hidden' name='QTY_REQUIRED' value='$row[QTY_REQUIRED]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[QTY_CNCED]<input type='hidden' name='QTY_CNCED' value='$row[QTY_CNCED]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[REQUESTER]<input type='hidden' name='REQUESTER' value='$row[REQUESTER]'/></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[REQUEST_DATE]<input type='hidden' name='REQUEST_DATE' value='$row[REQUEST_DATE]'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
    <input type='button' value='REJECT' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
  }// ends the WHILE loop
}// ends the IF
else if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $qtyToBeInserted = ($_POST[QTY_REQUESTED] + $_POST[QTY_CNCED]);

    $approvedSql = "UPDATE COMPONENT_CUTTING SET QTY_CNCED = :qtyToBeInserted WHERE BASE_PLATE = :basePlate 
                      AND THICKNESS = :thick AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName";

    $approvedSqlParse = oci_parse($conn, $approvedSql);

    oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "qtyToBeInserted", $qtyToBeInserted);
    oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "basePlate", $_POST[BASE_PLATE]);
    oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "thick", $_POST[THICKNESS]);
    oci_bind_by_name($approvedSqlParse, "projName", $_POST[PROJECT_NAME]);

    $approvedSqlRes = oci_execute($approvedSqlParse);

    if ($approvedSqlRes){
        oci_commit($conn);
        echo "SUCCESS!!" // or whatever you want to display on successful save
    } else {
        oci_rollback($conn);
        echo "ERROR!!" // or whatever you want to display when there was an error
    }
}// ends ELSE IF
```

Comment: Patrick so i edited the beginning of the PHP code with your suggestion, but on the new page, it doesnt do anything or even updating them value to the database.

Comment: You should probably extract the whole `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){` block outside of the `if (isset($_POST['action'])… ` block. Either that or add a hidden `action` element (with a value of 'show') to your generated forms, but that wouldn't be my suggestion. Currently, it looks like you're trying to merge together some functionality that probable shouldn't be. I'll try to update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you patrick, I really appreciate it, this is the full code just in case you want to review it. 

http://pastebin.com/PYVTcvd0

Comment: @Chriskonz See my update. I _think_ that will work for you. But considering that I don't really know what the overarching goal of the project is, it's hard for me to say if this is really the best way to do it. I have a hunch that what you really might want is to go with an ajax-based solution.

Comment: So is it better to do jQuery when button is clicked with onClick or onSubmit since all the values are stored inside the hidden input tag?

Comment: It is something that you should at least consider. Esp if you want to display the same collection of data after confirming one entry. There's no reason to fetch everything again. Just post the one confirmation via ajax. However, if you want to redirect to another page or show a simple success or failure status (as my example does), then there's no need for that and you can keep the simple form submit. That's really about the extent of what should be covered in this question/answer though. If my answer solved the problem asked in the question, please mark it as correct when you get a chance.

Comment: Patrick, inside the if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ tag,

i do want to test if the value passed properly, 
butsomehow it doesnt work, what happened here ?

echo $_POST["PROJECT_NAME"];                                                
                                                  echo $_POST["QTY_REQUESTED"];